# Room Database Errors

Tags: java, android, android-room, dao

I have this NoteDao.java

```
package com.learn.simplify.dao;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy;
import androidx.room.Query;

import com.learn.simplify.entities.Note;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC")
    List<Note> getAllNotes();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertNote(Note note);

    @Delete
    void deleteNote(Note note);
}
```

and it gives me this errors:

Cannot resolve symbol 'notes'
Cannot resolve symbol 'id'

also i tried changing to `public abstract NoteDao noteDao();` in NotesDatabse.java:

```
package com.learn.simplify.database;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

import com.learn.simplify.dao.NoteDao;
import com.learn.simplify.entities.Note;

@Database(entities = Note.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)

public abstract class NotesDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static NotesDatabase notesDatabase;
    public static synchronized NotesDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
        if(notesDatabase == null) {
            notesDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    NotesDatabase.class,
                    "notes_db"
            ).build();
        }
        return  notesDatabase;
    }
    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();

}
```

And i think maybe is still the error from Note.java, where i declared it all:

```
package com.learn.simplify.entities;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity(tableName = "notes")

public class Note implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "subtitle")
    private String subtitle;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date_time")
    private String dateTime;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_text")
    private String noteText;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_path")
    private String imagePath;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "color")
    private String color;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "web_link")
    private String webLink;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public String getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getNoteText() {
        return noteText;
    }

    public void setNoteText(String noteText) {
        this.noteText = noteText;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getWebLink() {
        return webLink;
    }

    public void setWebLink(String webLink) {
        this.webLink = webLink;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override

    public String toString(){
        return title +  " : " + dateTime;
    }
}
```

I tried rebuildind, cleaning, restartind the IDE and the PC, clearing cache, i even deleted all java autogenerated files, still the same error
[image: Error Image]

Comment: I had the same issue and just fixed it using this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73793503/3888401](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73793503/3888401)